# Splitting a value that is delimitted

Tags: vba, excel

transactions sheet

```
 ID1  Name Amount ID2 
 123   A     1   0;124;0 
 456   B     2   124;0;0  
 789   C     3   456;0;0
```

transactions sheet (Expected Result)

```
 ID1  Name Amount ID2   Summary
 123   A     1   0;124;0  124
 456   B     2   124;0;0  456
 789   C     3   456;0;0
```

I have tried text to columns but I am unsure on how to ignore all the 0's and only display the value if its >0 in column D. I am new to vba so would appreciate some advice on this so I can learn.

Code:

```
  Sub SplitRange()
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim str As Variant    'string array
  Dim r   As Integer
  For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   If InStr(cell.Value, ";") > 0 Then 'split
   str = Split(cell.Value, ";")
   For r = LBound(str) To UBound(str)
   cel.Offset(r).Value = Trim(str(r))
   If r < UBound(str) Then cell.Offset(r + 1).EntireRow.Insert
   Next r
   End If
  Next cell 
  End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to do that in VBA you would need to start something on your own first. This is a question/answer based site where you can ask questions related on code you have written on your own, and got stuck or got errors. People will kindly help you to fix your issues in your code yourself but they wont write all the code for you. Also it is too broad to ask for a general guidance or teaching here. You might take a [tour] or read [ask] to improve your question (and you need to ask one at least).

Comment: Appologies, I have added the code I have used, I am having trouble getting the summary part the split is ok.

Comment: I suggest to use `Option Explicit` to avoid any trouble with variable naming. Your biggest issue is that you once use `cel` and on the other hand you use `cell`. Also have a look at the formula solution below where you don't need VBA at all.

Comment: I would like to use vba to automate the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morning,

What you need here is to split the entry into an array and then check the values of the array as you loop the array:

```
Sub SplitString()

Dim TempArray() As String
Dim i as Integer
Dim j As Integer


For i = 1 To 10

    TempArray = Split(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,4).Value,";")

    For j = 0 to UBound(TempArray)

        If CDbl(TempArray(j)) <> 0 Then

              [Output value]

        End if

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Create a more useful loop than 1 = 1 to 10 but you get the idea...

Note in the above:
- The CDbl is to ensure that the check reads it as a number and not a text string.

Comment: Hi, this produces a compile error at row 1 I have done for i = 1 to 10000

Comment: can you please advise?

Comment: Sorry the first TempArray needs brackets i.e.
    Dim TempArray() as String
I have edited in the above.

Comment: Hi GLH - if that's all clear now, please upvote and mark it as a solution by clicking the tick.

Answer (score 1):

At first we should not loop through all used cells but only the row where these ID2 are that we need, which is a lot faster.

The easiest way would be just to remove all `;0` and `0;` then only the value remains. The following will work if there is always only one real value that is not `0` e.g `0;124;0`.

```
Public Sub FindValueRangeInColumn()
    Const Col As Long = 4   'the column where the ID2 is in

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To lRow 'loop throug rows from 2 to last used row
        Dim strSource As String
        strSource = ws.Cells(iRow, Col) 'read value

        strSource = Replace(ws.Cells(iRow, Col), ";0", "") 'remove all ;0
        If Left$(strSource, 2) = "0;" Then strSource = Right$(strSource, Len(strSource) - 2) 'remove 0; from the beginnning

        ws.Cells(iRow, Col + 1).Value = strSource 'write value
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

If there can be more than 1 non-zero value like `0;124;0;222;0;0;144` then replace

```
ws.Cells(iRow, Col + 1).Value = strSource 'write value
```

with a splitting alternative …

```
    If InStr(1, strSource, ";") > 1 Then
        Dim SplitValues As Variant
        SplitValues = Split(strSource, ";")
        Dim iValue As Long
        For iValue = LBound(SplitValues) To UBound(SplitValues)
            ws.Cells(iRow, Col + 1 + iValue).Value = SplitValues(iValue) 'write value
        Next iValue
    Else
        ws.Cells(iRow, Col + 1).Value = strSource 'write value
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to concatenate non-0 values into a string, then put that in the next cell?

```
Sub SplitRange()
    Dim workcell As Range
    Dim str() As String 'string array
    Dim r As Long 'VBA automatically stores Integers as Longs, so there is no Memory saved by not using Long
    Dim output As String
    output = ";" 'Start with a single delimiter

    For Each workcell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange,ActiveSheet.Columns(4)) 'Go down the cells in Column D
        If InStr(workcell.Value, ";") > 0 Then 'split
            str = Split(workcell.Value,";")
            For r = LBound(str) To UBound(str)
                If inStr(output, ";" & Trim(str(r)) & ";") < 1 Then 'If number is not already in output
                    output = output & Trim(str(r)) & ";" 'Add the number and ";" to the end of the string
                End If
            Next r
            Erase str 'Tidy up array, ready to recycle
        End If
    Next workcell
    'We now have a unique list of all items, starting/ending/delimited with ";"
    output = Replace(output,";0;",";") 'Remove the item ";0;" if it exists
    If Len(output) > 2 Then 'output contains at least 1 non-zero number
        output= Mid(output,2,len(output)-2) 'Remove ";" from the start and end
        str = Split(output,";") 'Split the list of unique values into an array
        For r = lbound(str) To ubound(str)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r+2-lbound(str),5).Value = str(r) 'List the values in column 5, starting from row 2
        Next r
        Erase str 'Tidy up array
    End If
End Sub
```

To remove "0"s from a single row as an Excel formula, try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("|;" & A1 & ";|", ";0;",";"),";|",""),"|;","")
```

From the inside-out:

> `SUBSTITUTE("|;" & A1 & ";|", ";0;",";")` Sandwich our values in wrappers (`"|;0;240;0;|"`) and replace any ";0;" with ";" (`"|;240;|"`)

.

> `SUBSTITUTE(PREV,";|","")` Remove ";|" (`"|;240"`)

.

> `SUBSTITUTE(PREV,"|;","")` Remove "|;" (`"240"`)

Comment: Hi, subscript out of range "for r = lbound (str) to ubound(str)

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. How do I include the unique Id's in the next column? as per my expected result shown in the question description. Also if there are many 0s and not just one then the formula does not work is there a way to do this for all 0's? Ie 100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 would return 100.

Comment: @GLH Updated - I dyked too much of your existing code out when adapting it.  Sorry!

Comment: appreciate the help on this

Comment: Could you advise? please can you check my expected result

Comment: @GLH Ah, I had misread the question as removing the "0" items from each row in turn.  I have updated the answer to list unique non-zero items from column 4 in column 5.

Comment: I get a compile error: Expected: List Separator on line:

If inStr(";" & Trim(str(r)) & ";") < 1 Then

Comment: Corrected and tested.

Comment: Thank you this is now working I have accepted your answer